# JavaFX-2: how to get window size if it wasn't set manually?

Tags: java, javafx-2

I want to open a dialog window above the center of its parent window, so I use the following formula:

```
Window window = ((Node) actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(new DialogWindow()));
Stage dialog = new Stage();
dialog.initOwner(window);
dialog.sizeToScene();

dialog.setX(stage.getX() + stage.getWidth() / 2 - dialog.getWidth() / 2); //dialog.getWidth() = NaN
dialog.setY(stage.getY() + stage.getHeight() / 2 - dialog.getHeight() / 2); //dialog.getHeight() = NaN

dialog.setScene(scene);
dialog.show(); //it is better to showAndWait();
```

I don't set size the manually because I need the window to be sized automatically to the size of its content.

Under Linux it sets window straight in the center of the parent window. But in Windows it doesn't work and leads to different results.

How can I get the dialog's width and height if I don't set them manually?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The width and height of `Stage` are calculated after it has been shown (`.show()`). Do the calculation after it:

```
...
dialog.show();
dialog.setX(stage.getX() + stage.getWidth() / 2 - dialog.getWidth() / 2); //dialog.getWidth() = not NaN
dialog.setY(stage.getY() + stage.getHeight() / 2 - dialog.getHeight() / 2); //dialog.getHeight() = not NaN
```

**EDIT:**
If `showAndWait()` is used instead of `show()`, then since `showAndWait()` blocks the caller event the calculations after the `showAndWait()` are also blocked. The one way of workaround could be doing calculation before in new `Runnable`:

```
final Stage dialog = new Stage();
dialog.initOwner(window);
dialog.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
dialog.sizeToScene();
dialog.setScene(scene);

Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        dialog.setX(primaryStage.getX() + primaryStage.getWidth() / 2 - dialog.getWidth() / 2); //dialog.getWidth() = NaN
        dialog.setY(primaryStage.getY() + primaryStage.getHeight() / 2 - dialog.getHeight() / 2); //dialog.getHeight() = NaN
    }
});
dialog.showAndWait();
```

Note also on `initModality`. The modality must be set in case of `showAndWait()`. Otherwise using `showAndWait()` has no sense.

Comment: It works. But for only `show()`. For `showAndWait()` there's a problem, if main window was moved. If I move it aside, dialog will still appear in the center of the screen. Anyway thanks for such solution and I'll keep seeking for solution for `showAndWait()` :)

Comment: Just for the sake of adding Scene in the dance I've used `double px = myScene.getWindow().getX(); double py = myScene.getWindow().getY();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
System.out.println(screenBounds.getHeight());
System.out.println(screenBounds.getWidth());
```

Comment: This is the size of the screen and not useful for the question asked. However it might be useful elsewhere and is a handy piece of information. This is , unfortunately, just the wrong place for it.